# Rename [poochy-yoshi-wooly-world] to [poochy-and-yoshis-wooly-world]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I propose renaming the tag for Poochy & Yoshi's Woolly World from [poochy-yoshi-wooly-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poochy-yoshi-wooly-world) to [poochy-and-yoshis-wooly-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poochy-and-yoshis-wooly-world).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we've had a typo in the name the whole time, as "wooly" actually has two L's in it according to the Nintendo website.

Renamed it to [poochy-and-yoshis-woolly-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poochy-and-yoshis-woolly-world)